# Как найти средне взвешиваное в списке с помощью numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Я вызываю numpy
А что дальше делать?

Comment: Искать средне взвешиваное в списке

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, то средневзвешенное - это когда суммируют список, умножая элементы на некие "веса" и потом делят на сумму этих весов, как-то так:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
weights = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.15])
average_weighted = (numbers * weights).sum()/weights.sum()
print(average_weighted)
# 2.85
```

А вот просто среднее было бы:

```
print(numbers.mean())
# 3.0
```

Comment: А можно ли вычесть средне взвешиваное без веса

Comment: @АлексейР Тогда оно будет просто среднее. У вас какие-то данные на входе есть, вообще что-то есть ещё? Всё что есть добавляйте в вопрос.

Comment: У меня на вход даётся список из случайных чисел из него как раз нужно вычесть

Comment: @АлексейР Понимаете, в слове "средневзвешенное" есть как бы "вес" в середине, то, чем "взвешивают". Поэтому должны быть какие-то веса. Без весов может быть только просто среднее.